# Difficulty in adding libraries to codeassist app

Tags: java, android, okhttp, libraries

I have been looking for ways to add OkHttp, or any other library, to the codeassist app. I do hope there is a solution to this?

Googling, asking experienced programmers in my locality. I really do hope to gain from your experience.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 0:

Go to https://mvnrepository.com and search for the library you want for example [okhttp](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/) select version you want, in maven section find some information like this, save it you will need it next steps.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>4.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

### step 1: Click on file icon

[image]

### Step 2: Click on Library manager

[image]

### Step 3: Click on add icon

[image]

### step 4: Fill with library info that you want to add for example okhttp

[image]

### step 5: Click Refresh module

[image]